# Publishing build uploaded to iTunes Connect before provisioning profile change

Tags: app-store-connect

(This is essentially a question about iTunes Connect but I'm not sure if it's more appropriate here or on SO)

Several weeks ago I uploaded an iOS build of our app to iTunes Connect for submission to Apple. Afterward, we started working on a newer version with added support for push notifications, which required us to create new provisioning profiles. I also uploaded a new build to TestFlight with a new minor version number.

I just found out that the person responsible for submitting the previous build for approval never did so, so it's still waiting for submission. Since the provisioning profile change, our last build on TestFlight can no longer be installed because the provisioning profile is no longer valid. Does that mean that the build waiting for submission to the review team is also no longer valid?

iTunes Connect generally forces you to increase your version number with each build. Since I already uploaded a version to TestFlight with an increased minor version number, there is no way to upload a new build with the previous minor version number?

Comment: I think you'll find answers both here and SO.  However, my experience has been that I get more detailed and complete development-related answers on SO.  I haven't had a similar problem using iTC but I don't think you upload a 'newer' build with an older version number.  You might have to upload an even newer build with the updates from both previous builds (I hope that made sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up submitting the build to Apple for approval and they approved it, so apparently the provisioning profile on the build waiting for review was still valid.